# determine if empty set in hook_views_pre_views()

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to find out how many results are returned inside `hook_views_pre_views()` using Views 3 ?

What i've tried is to use `$views->total_rows` but that provides a false positive. I'm guessing because my view uses display suite to render the result?

e.g.

`custom.module`

```
<?php
/* 
 * Implements hook_views_pre_views()
 */
function custom_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' && $display_id == 'block') {
        // Find out if results are empty; if so unset the view footer
        // Not sure what to do here?
        if ( ...) {
            // After rows check, unset my view footer which contains a view block
            $view->display_handler->options['footer'] = array();
        }
    }
}
```

Overall, i'm trying to programmatically unset the views footer. I've tried the "No Results" settings in the UI; but for some reason it always returns the child "View Area" i've attached in the View Footer.

Comment: The description for that hook is _Allows altering a view at the very beginning of views processing, before anything is done._ I would take that to mean that no query has been run yet, so there aren't any results to count. (that's assuming you meant [`hook_views_pre_view()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7), without the 's' at the end?)

Comment: I see i guess i'm asking the wrong question. Would you know which [hooks](http://www.kdweb.co.uk/blog/drupal-module-views-hook-sequence) would normally contain results?

Comment: `hook_views_pre_render()` is pretty much guaranteed to contain the results (or an indication there were no results), and it happens early enough for you to alter rendering